# Router resolve activated twice in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on Angular 2 project. The situation is that I have a route and this route have a resolver which look like this.

```
  {
    path: 'detail/:id/:year', component: VerticalComponent, pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    resolve: {
        aximaticData: DetailDataResolver
    }
}
```

and here is the **DetailDataResolver**

```
 @Injectable()
 export class DetailDataResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {}

     public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
         return this._httpService.httpGet(URL.DASHBOARD_SIDEMENU, true);
    }
}
```

I am activating this route like this.

```
<a href="/detail/1/2015"></a>
```

Now the problem is resolver is activated twice. Why it is activated twice and how can I handle this?

Comment: can you try with routerLink instead? `<a routerLink='/detail/1/2015'></a>`

Comment: @vishal thanx man it works